# Same ImageDataGenerator but different class_indices - How to remap the classes within a generator?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, generator

### Background

I am training a model that takes as inputs two images. As the data is too large to fit into my machines RAM, I am using `flow_from_dataframe` to create the generators for training and validation - two training generators which each provide one of the respective images (front view & back view as indicated by the `x_col` parameter) and two generators for validation respectively.

Like this:

```
datagen=ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1. / 255)

X1_train_generator =datagen.flow_from_dataframe(dataframe=train, directory=data_dir, x_col="front", y_col=target, has_ext=True, class_mode="categorical", target_size=(224,224), batch_size=batch_size,seed = 1)
X2_train_generator=datagen.flow_from_dataframe(dataframe=train, directory=data_dir, x_col="back", y_col=target, has_ext=True, class_mode="categorical", target_size=(224,224), batch_size=batch_size,seed = 1)

X1_validation_generator =datagen.flow_from_dataframe(dataframe=test, directory=data_dir, x_col="front", y_col=target, has_ext=True, class_mode="categorical", target_size=(224,224), batch_size=batch_size,seed = 1)
X2_validation_generator=datagen.flow_from_dataframe(dataframe=test, directory=data_dir, x_col="back", y_col=target, has_ext=True, class_mode="categorical", target_size=(224,224), batch_size=batch_size,seed = 1)
```

In order to combine the train and validation generator for training I am using:

```
def format_gen_outputs(gen1,gen2):
    x1 = gen1[0]
    x2 = gen2[0]
    y1 = gen1[1]
    return [x1, x2], y1

train_combo_gen= map(format_gen_outputs, X1_train_generator , X2_train_generator )
validation_combo_gen= map(format_gen_outputs, X1_validation_generator , X2_validation_generator )
```

Now I use `fit_generator` to train my model passing `train_combo_gen` for training purpose and `validation_combo_gen` to the `validation_data` parameter for validation purpose

### Problem

However, I realize that both my `X1_train_generator` and `X2_train_generator` show a different `.class_indices` mapping than my other two validation generators `X1_validation_generator` and `X2_validation_generator`.

Like this (notice how cat & dog are assigned to different classes):

```
X1_train_generator.class_indices
>> {'cat': 0, 'dog': 1, 'car': 2, 'bike': 3}

X1_validation_generato.class_indices
>> {'dog': 0, 'cat': 1, 'car': 2, 'bike': 3}
```

### Question

Hence, I don't trust my `val_loss` and `val_acc` during training. Is there any way to fix this i.e. remap the classes within the generators?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you don't explicitly set the classes using `classes` argument, the `flow_from_dataframe` internally uses pandas Series [`unique`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unique.html) method on the `y_col` column [to find the classes](https://github.com/keras-team/keras-preprocessing/blob/7b7af2690026b51b5a7a50b4b359ff12960ac8b7/keras_preprocessing/image.py#L2107):

```
if not classes:
    classes = []
    if class_mode not in ["other", "input", None]:
        classes = list(self.df[y_col].unique())
```

The `unique` method would return the unique values in order of appearance in the column. Since the order of appearance of labels in your train and test dataframe are different from each other, you would get different indices for classes.

One workaround is to explicitly set the `classes` argument for all the `flow_from_dataframe` calls to guarantee the same class indices mapping in train and validation generators:

```
X1_train_generator =datagen.flow_from_dataframe(dataframe=train, 
                                                classes=['cat', 'dog', 'car', 'bike'], ...)

# do the same for `X2_train_generator`, `X1_validation_generator` and `X2_validation_generator`
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This is exactly what I was looking for. Totally missed the fact that there is a classes parameter!